# Rendering image on the screen efficiently with multi-platform support?

Tags: c++, image, visual-c++, rendering, multiplatform

I'm making some kind of image viewer/editor program, that would work on all the 3 main platforms.

I know I can't use OpenGL, because this program should work with the crappiest GFX cards available, meaning there may not be OpenGL drivers available.

How does the other programs draw on the screen so fast without using hardware acceleration? (GFX card).

I have used SDL previously to render pixels on the screen, could that be the solution? Or should I implement the image rendering separately for all 3 main systems (Windows,Mac,Linux) ? And if so, which libraries to use for all of those 3 systems?

I won't need any fancy animation, just plain still images, which I may zoom in/out and move with mouse. I don't know how the image moving would work, since that would have to update all the pixels on the screen, which will be very slow, is there any tricks to optimize that? (without hardware acceleration).

For example Paint Shop Pro 7 has very optimized image viewing, I don't think it uses my GPU at all, and it is very fast too, how can I achieve that speed myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL works on all three platforms (windows, linux, mac). It's fixed pipeline is supported even on crappiest graphical cards.

Image rendering can be done using textures, and that is supported on every card.

Mouse manipulation has to be done in SDL (or other framework).

If you choose not to use opengl, you can use qt, which is almost platform independent.

Comment: The problem with OpenGL is that i would have to push the whole image into GPU memory at once, and that is slow operation even on my machine. Instead, i would only push it to RAM and render the image with current zoom level pixel by pixel. Maybe it is enough fast to send full-screen pixels to the screen memory in 60fps, last time i tried i was able to do that at maximum of 1024x768 resolution or something like that. Also, i dont see the point using OpenGL if i dont need any special effects or real time animation: after all, i only render the image _once_, and then it is kept in the buffer.

Comment: Do you have any idea how fast would qt be? care to show some programs that are made with qt and which displays large images on screen which can be scrolled smoothly?

Comment: @Rookie Besides needing more memory, I think it will be slower then opengl+sdl. If you are limited by the HW, then there isn't much you can do

Answer (score 0):

What I've done to have multi-platform drawing is write an abstraction layer on top of the drawing routines of each platform (Winforms or WPF for windows, Core Graphics for OS X, and Cairo for Linux).  It is open source here:  https://github.com/picoe/Eto

This is currently in use for a drawing application, which supports animation so it is performant enough for many scenarios:  http://picoe.ca/products/pablodraw

One thing that may or may not be to your liking (depending on how you look at it) is that it is written in .NET/C#.

Comment: Any other projects that use it? I wasnt able to test it fully in the Pablo Draw, since it doesnt support zooming or dragging the image, so i could see the performance how fast it does it.

Comment: PabloDraw does support zooming (View->Zoom), which uses image scaling to perform that, and dragging of images if you select a region and press 'c' to copy, it will show the image moving along with the mouse.
There's some commercial software currently being built using it but nothing that I can link to, sorry.

Comment: Another note is when you are scrolling, it is actually painting the canvas as you go (it is not static).  So even the scroll speed should give you some indication of its performance.

Comment: The problem is i cant scroll in that program... i tried zoom but it does nothing. only way the zoom works is when i resize the window smaller. also, i cant even edit the images i open(?)

Comment: It is an ansi/ascii/ripscrip editor, it does not edit images like jpg/png/etc, it can only view those.

Comment: i have no idea what "ripscrip" means. Anyways, i was able to test scrolling now: created new ripscrip document and resized my window very small, and then scrolled. Seems to be very fast, hard to say though, because window is so small! Maybe i will move to C# just to be able to use this code of yours. Its free to use for commercial purposes too? OR do i need to buy license?

Comment: It's BSD licensed so you can use it commercially at no cost.  Try creating a text document or opening a long .txt document, then editing it.